# Dynamic range for window functions

Tags: google-bigquery

Consider a timeseries dataset with daily observations where we want to use a window function to calculate some sum over the past 30 days. This is pretty straight-forward:

```
SELECT
  some_date,
  SUM(some_var)
    OVER (PARTITION BY some_other_var ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(some_date) RANGE BETWEEN 29 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS sum_past_30d
FROM some_table
```

But what I really want to do is to sum over the past month, accounting for the fact that the number of days may vary between months. Eg. from 2023-01-15 to 2023-02-15.

I tried the following, it fails because `RANGE` requires a literal or a parameter :

```
SELECT *,
  SUM(some_var)
    OVER (PARTITION BY some_other_var ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(some_date) RANGE BETWEEN n_days PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS sum_past_month
FROM (
  SELECT 
    some_date, 
    some_var, 
    some_other_var,
    DATE_DIFF(dato, DATE_SUB(dato, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), DAY) AS n_days
  FROM some_table
)
```

Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Comment: I would doubt this is supported, as it has to create a unique window for each row, and this is probably not very efficient. I would probably tackle this by summing over a default 30 day window, then either adding or subtracting lag/lead values for 28/29/31 day months, but this will require some custom logic.